# How can i have access to the custom-post-type through a category

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

i have this issue:
I need access to the custom-post-type's content(archive-destinos.php) when i clic over the countries's category. I explain, i have a CPT "Destinos" which have a lot of countries grouped by a category "Países"(countries). The CPT code is working perfectly when i access through the slug(/destinos). The problem is when i clic over the category "Países" (countries) because have different slug(/category/paises). Im really new in wordpress and cant find a solution for this issue.
I'm really desperate and I cant find a solution, if someone was so kind to help i will appreciate it!!

This is the the CPT:

```
function register_my_cpts_destinos() {
$labels = array(
    "name" => __( "Destinos", "" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "Destino", "" ),
    "menu_name" => __( "Destinos", "" ),
);
$args = array(
    "label" => __( "Destinos", "" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "has_archive" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "destinos", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt", "trackbacks", "custom-fields", "comments", "revisions", "author", "page-attributes", "post-formats" ),
);
register_post_type( "destinos", $args );
```

}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_cpts_destinos' );

Comment: You are expected to post your current `code` effort within your question because otherwise, you are unlikely to get any answers. (just the way it works here)

Comment: i hope this was enough because i can explain more clear, please help me